# When using ffmpeg to encode an MP4 for general consumption, should I set the profile and IDC level? (-profile:v and -level:v)

Tags: ffmpeg

Should I bother setting them at all? Basically, what is the guidance on setting these properties?

The specific ffmpeg flags I'm referring to are `-level:v` and `-profile:v`.

The video is intended for general consumption, direct download (not embedded in a web page). So most users will probably play the video however their device tells them to. I would like to know what's the best practice so that the highest number of users can view it without problems.

[This question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24476/how-to-choose-the-right-bitrate-h-264-profile-and-level-for-web-video-presentat) asks something similar, but it has no answer about these two settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the encoder set the level automatically. The encoder will have a default `profile` (High for x264) and higher the profile, better quality for a given bitrate or lower bitrate for a certain quality target. Unless you have compatibility concerns, default High is fine as well.